# Getting User is not set using mailgun in Laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel-10, mailgun-api

I'm trying to setup mailgun in Laravel 10 using the Mailgun API. The mail is using the laravel queue. When the queue tries to send the email I receive this error:

```
production.ERROR: User is not set. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Mailer\\Exception\\IncompleteDsnException(code: 0): User is not set. at /var...../class/releases/20231124151624/vendor/symfony/mailer/Transport/AbstractTransportFactory.php:44)
```

Because I use the API my .env looks like this:

```
MAIL_MAILER=mailgun
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=mg.*****.nl
MAILGUN_SECRET=afb*****
MAILGUN_ENDPOINT=api.eu.mailgun.net
```

Ik I use these settings on my development machine everything works, but on the production server, I get the "user not set" error.
I tried using the API in a curl command on the server, this also works fine:

```
curl -s --user 'api:afb***' \
    https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3/mg.***.nl/messages \
    -F from='Excited User <mailgun@mg.***.nl>' \
    -F to=****@gmail.com \
    -F subject='Hello' \
    -F text='Testing some Mailgun awesomeness!'
```

(example from mailgun docs)
Laravel config as instructed in Laravel DOC:
mail.php

```
        'mailgun' => [
            'transport' => 'mailgun',
        ],
```

and services.php

```
    'mailgun' => [
        'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
        'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
        'endpoint' => env('MAILGUN_ENDPOINT', 'api.eu.mailgun.net')
    ],
```

to make sure I cleared all caching on the server (better one too many than not enough)

```
    php artisan clear-compiled
    php artisan cache:clear
    php artisan view:clear
    php artisan config:clear
    php artisan route:clear
    php artisan optimize:clear

    composer dump-autoload
    composer clear-cache
```

and I restarted apache but nothing seems to work. Because it works fine on my local machine, I think the code must be OK. But I am at a loss what else to try. Please help!